# Zerofill with Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

It looks like an easy task, but I can't get it done:
How do I define a column to be UNSIGNED ZEROFILL with Doctrine2?

I can't find any information about it in the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html).

Thx for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you need it on database level or is it required only by the application? You could append zeros on the application level:

```
class MyEntity {
    public function getSomeColumn() {
        return sprintf('%05d', $this->someColumn); // or str_pad(...)
    }
}
```

However if you really need it on database level then you'll have to annotate the column as a string: `@Column(type="string", columnDefinition="UNSIGNED INTEGER(5) ZEROFILL")`

Comment: A custom mapping type here could be useful to get the schema generated and updated correctly.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain the `'%05d'` part of your answer

Answer (score 2):

The good syntax is :

```
@Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="INT(5) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the (non-portable) `columnDefinition` property in the [`@Column`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column) annotation.

Comment: You mean like this: `@Column(type="integer", columnDefinition="UNSIGNED ZEROFILL")`? Did try that, it's not working.

Comment: @sprain: It's not working cause you declare a column as an integer where it's supposed to be a string.